# HTML Button name, containing full URI

Tags: html, button, uri

is it possible, to store on a button attribute, a full path of a file?`<button name="folder/green.txt (1)">FullName</button>`

In case that this is not possible, how could I save a full URI path on a button?

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: The problem is that the special characters do not translate, like the (1) or the .txt  Do you know how to translate the full URI to something like the HTML interpreter understand?

Comment: does it specifically have to be the `name` that accepts the entire file path? To what ultimate end is this required?

Comment: This reads like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Have you tried it? Did it work? Did you achieve what you wanted to achieve? How did the results differ from what you wanted? "The problem is that the special characters do not translate, like the (1) or the .txt" — Edit updates into your question so they aren't buried in comments. Why should they be translated? Browsers only implicitly convert illegal characters into escape sequences in URLs when they are treating input as a URL… which a name isn't designed to be used for.

Comment: I just pass a value to the name attribute of a button, I just solved it putting the name attribute with his respective commas, like ``<button name='$nameFile'></button>`` That worked for me, @ProfessorAbronsius @Quentin